# Creating a Desktop shortcut Eclipse on Linux Mint

Tags: terminal, filesystems, linux-mint

I installed Eclipse using the Software Manager (mintInstall) on Linux Mint 15. I am trying to create an Eclipse shortcut on my Desktop via Terminal. I looked it up and found out about the mkshct command. However, I have the following problems:

Where did the Software Manager install Eclipse? (Other applications on too while on this topic)

Am I on the right track using mkshct?

Answer (score 2):

How I solved this issue:

1. Open the downloaded file (it will have `eclipse`, `eclipse.ini`, `epl-v10.html`, etc.)
2. Right click on the eclipse file (the same file that launches Eclipse) and click on **Make a Link**, than drag the link to your desktop.

The Eclipse package also contains `icon.xpm` if you want to change the link/desktop icon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is in /opt/eclipse/.
P.S. Download from eclipse.org new version and you can run eclipse without installing from the folder.

Comment: I found this solution on the web just now. However, there is no eclipse in my opt folder. It is possible that mintInstall downloaded and installed from eclipse.org but I still can't create a shortcut this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Start Menu option on the bottom right, search for Eclipse.

Once you find it (normally found under 'Development') just drag the icon to the desktop and a shortcut will be made for it.

Answer (score 0):

CLI approach:

> `% which eclipse`
>
> `% /xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/eclipse`
>
> `% ln -s /xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/eclipse /yyyy/yyyy/yyyy`

where `/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/eclipse` is output of `% which eclipse` and `/yyyy/yyyy/yyyy` is where you want symbolic-link(shortcut)

> > we type "which eclipse" to know where your eclipse is installed

Answer (score 0):

first check Eclipse path `$ which eclipse`

```
1. $ sudo apt install gedit
2. $ cd Desktop
3. $ touch eclipse.desktop
4. $ gedit eclipse.desktop
5.
```

**syntax:**

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=Name of your application 
    Icon=/path/to/icon
    Exec=/path/to/application
```

You have to edit Name, Icon and Exec

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=eclipse
Icon=/home/mypc/SOFTWARES/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/mypc/SOFTWARES/eclipse/eclipse
```

6. Make it executable

   chmod u+x eclipse.desktop